# removing grid lines in C# Chart & making thicker graph lines

Tags: c#, charts

I'm using the built in chart class of .net 4 and I just cant find a way to remove the grid lines on the chart. Is there a way of doing it?
And another question, how do I make the graph lines thicker?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the line width can be changed using `BorderWidth` and `BorderDashStyle` of the series.

For the gridlines, try playing with `MajorGrid`, `MinorGrid`, `MajorTickMark`, `MinorTickMark` and `Interval` on the axis.

Answer (score 18):

```
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
```

This will remove gridlines from chartarea.

Answer (score 1):

with the chart selected go to its settings menu and click into chartarea(collection).go to Axes(collection) clicking on this will open a new menu. you will find the grid settings under gridtickmarks-majorgrid. with this you can change/delete the grid with no code required.