# Removing gridlines from graph

Tags: c#, graph

I am printing  a graph on a page. I could draw and modify the graph, but it have some grid lines which can not be altered or removed. Here is the code and screen shot :

```
        Chart chart2 = new Chart();
        ChartArea area2 = new ChartArea();

        chart2.ChartAreas.Add(area2);
        Series s2 = new Series();
        s2.Name = "S2";
        s2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        s2.XValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
        s2.YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
        chart2.Series.Add(s2);
        chart2.Series["S2"].Points.DataBindXY(x2, y2);


        Rectangle myRec1 = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(30,25,100,100);
        // draw!
        chart2.Printing.PrintPaint(e.Graphics, myRec1);
```

Image  : [image: Screen shot]

I tried almost all properties of series and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826998/removing-grid-lines-in-c-sharp-chart-making-thicker-graph-lines) but I think it is not the reason for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the suitable ones of the following statements to your code;

```
area2.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled  = False
area2.AxisX2.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
area2.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled  = False
area2.AxisY2.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
area2.AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled  = False
area2.AxisX2.MinorGrid.Enabled = False
area2.AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled  = False
area2.AxisY2.MinorGrid.Enabled = False
```